# Defend Against Reentrancy and Invariant Violations When Using INotifyPropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, inotifypropertychanged, reentrancy, invariants

When using `INotifyPropertyChanged` there is a risk of reentrancy bugs because the `PropertyChanged` event handler could call a method on the sender directly or indirectly. Because the typical implementation raises these events as soon as the property is assigned, this is a hidden source of reentrancy points throughout methods. Any time a property is assigned, one would need to guard against reentrancy.

In addition, the `PropertyChanged` event may expose the object when it is in a state that violates one of its class invariants. For example, a class invariant states that if and only property `A` is true, then property `B` will be non-null. Naive code to assign `A` then `B` will cause a property changed event to fire when only one has changed. The event handler will then observe the object in this state when the class invariant has been violated but not yet restored.

These issues are less of a concern when implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on view models. Updating the UI is unlikely to involve code that would cause these problems. However, many people implement it on models as well because it greatly simplifies updating the UI. There, it seems more of a concern. I see very little discussion of these issues online even when I search for them. (I did find [INotifyPropertyChanged and consistency - when to raise PropertyChanged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22805169/268898))

My question has two parts:

1. When implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on *model* objects, should I defend against reentrancy and constraint violation issues? Why or why not?
2. Is there an *easy* way, without boilerplate, to defend against reentrancy and constraint violation issues? (I've seen suggestions to delay raising change events, but that would seem to require either always explicitly/manually raising change events at the end of the method which would be error-prone, or use a framework and wrap every method body in a using statement that delays change events inside the using statement.)

Answer (score 2):

### Short and quick solution:

- Don't use property setters which raise `PropertyChanged`, instead update your model's state using `private` methods which update the object's state atomically (thus preserving object invariants and constraints) and only raise `PropertyChanged` afterwards.
- You'll need to be careful to avoid invoking property setters from your own code, though. This could be done applying `[Obsolete]` or writing your own Roslyn Analyzer.

e.g.:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void DoSomethingThatUpdatesProperties()
    {
        // Update backing fields directly:
        this.text1 = "foo";
        this.text2 = "bar";

        // Only raise events afterwards:
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof(this.Text1) ) );
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof(this.Text2) ) );
    }
    
    private String text1;
    public String Text1
    {
        get => this.text1;
        set
        {
            if( this.text1 != value )
            {
                this.text1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.Text1) );
            }
        }
    }

    private String text2;
    public String Text2
    {
        get => this.text2;
        set
        {
            if( this.text2 != value )
            {
                this.text2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.Text2) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Another idea: use a custom `IDisposable` to manage deferring of events:

```
sealed class MutationMonitor : IDisposable
{
    public MutationMonitor( Action onDispose )
    {
        this.onDispose = onDispose;
    }

    private readonly Action onDispose;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.onDispose();
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Boolean isMutating = false;
    private readonly HashSet<String> changedProperties = new HashSet<String>();

    public void DoSomethingThatUpdatesProperties()
    {
        using( this.BeginStateMutationMethod() )
        {
            this.Text1 = "foo";
            this.Text2 = "bar";
        }
    }

    private void MutationMonitor BeginStateMutationMethod()
    {
        this.isMutating = true;
        return new MutationMonitor( this.EndStateMutationMethod );
    }

    private void EndStateMutationMethod()
    {
        this.isMutating = false;
        foreach( String p in this.changedProperties ) this.raiseInpcEvent( p );
        this.changedProperties.Clear();
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged( String name )
    {
        if( this.isMutating )
        {
            this.changedProperties.Add( name );
        }
        else
        {
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
        }
    }
    
    private String text1;
    public String Text1
    {
        get => this.text1;
        set
        {
            if( this.text1 != value )
            {
                this.text1 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.Text1) );
            }
        }
    }

    private String text2;
    public String Text2
    {
        get => this.text2;
        set
        {
            if( this.text2 != value )
            {
                this.text2 = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.Text2) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Idealistic solution: Use Redux

> When implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on model objects, should I defend against reentrancy and constraint violation issues? Why or why not?

I'm unsure what you're referring to, specifically, by the term "model object", but in short: **yes**, for the exact reasons you mentioned in your post, but also because it can lead to infinite loops when two properties on an `INotifyPropertyChanged` object are bound to each other, and if there's nondeterminism going on or where equality is difficult to define (e.g. with IEEE-754 numbers) then you'll probably end-up in a recursive infinite loop.

I gather in WPF and UWP, it employs techniques to avoid unwanted *knock-on effects* in the same dispatch cycle but I'm unsure about the specifics (but this is why you *need* a `Dispatcher` when Unit Testing view-models)

> Is there an easy way, without boilerplate, to defend against reentrancy and constraint violation issues? (I've seen suggestions to delay raising change events, but that would seem to require either always explicitly/manually raising change events at the end of the method which would be error-prone, or use a framework and wrap every method body in a using statement that delays change events inside the using statement.)

Yes: by using immutable-state with the Redux Pattern. This forces a *one-way data-flow* which makes it considerably easier to reason about UI state, and thanks to C# 9.0's new immutable `record` types there's a lot less tedium involved in instantiating the *next* state.

The Redux pattern isn't a panacea though: certain types of applications are not well-suited to the Redux pattern: such as those handling large amounts of stateful data (e.g. a huge spreadsheet or scatter plot chart with tens of thousands of data-points), owing to the performance implications of reallocating and mapping immutable state with mutable UI (XAML/WPF) components. But YMMV and there are some surprising optimizations that can be done.

You don't need a Redux library to implement the pattern - I've reviewed a few extant Redux libraries for WPF and none of them really agree with me - or they have opinionated implementations I'm religiously opposed to - or when it's just easier to write my own.

---

So rather than doing this:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private void OnPropertyChanged( String name )
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( name ) );
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private String text;
    public String Text
    {
        get => this.text;
        set
        {
            if( this.text != value )
            {
                this.text = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged( nameof(this.Text) );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd have this:

- Note that this is an extremely simplified example that only uses a single type (`MyState`) to represent the entirety of immutable state. This is unrealistic - but I don't have the mental energy right now to provide a more complete example.
- Also this example has the Redux Actions implemented as methods on `MyState` (e.g. `MyState.SetText`) instead of as pure state-transition reduction functions defined centrally.

```
class MyState
{
    public MyState( String text )
    {
        this.Text = text;
    }

    public String Text { get; }

    //

    public MyState SetText( String newText )
    {
        return new MyState( newText ) ;
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly MyReduxStore store;
    private MyState state;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public MyViewModel( MyReduxStore store )
    {
        this.store = store;
        this.store.Subscribe( next => this.OnStateUpdated( next ) );
    }

    private void OnStateUpdated( MyState next )
    {
        MyState prev = this.state;
        this.state = next;

        // Call `PropertyChanged?.Invoke(...)` for all properties, if changed, here:
        if( prev.Text = next.Text ) this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof(this.Text) ) );
        // etc
    }

    public String Text
    {
        get => this.state.Text;
        set
        {
            this.store.Dispatch( new ReduxAction( state.SetText, value ) );
            // Observe that `PropertyChanged` is NOT invoked here!
        }
    }
}
```

But yes, there's tedium - but using tools like T4 helps reduce that down.